# 6GB of "System Storage" on iPhone 6 - Reset Doesn't Clear It

Tags: macos, iphone, storage

I have had issues with my iPhone's System Storage category taking up anywhere from 6 to 9 GB of storage.  This is a huge problem for me, as I have a 16GB phone!

I have backed up and wiped my phone in every possible combination multiple times over the last year or so and nothing helps.  Plugging it into iTunes and letting it sit open for a few minutes will clear less than 500 MB, and eventually that gets racked back up again.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or is my phone just screwed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have you searched this site for answers already provided to this problem?  There's a few dozen answers posted already, any of those could help you.  Try those and [edit] your question with what didn't work.

Comment: I just checked two vastly different devices, one a 16GB the other a 64GB. Both show System at about 8GB, so you're doing well ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal.

You can try clear unused files by restoring your iPhone from a backup.

You can also store your other files on iCloud to not take up space on the device. Some cases also offer additional storage. See [here](https://support.apple.com/HT203097) on how to clear up storage space.

Additionally, see [iPhone System taking up Storage space.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8095398)

Comment: I have done multiple restores and backups with this phone and nothing has fixed it.  I use Google Photos to keep pictures and I delete attachments from texts every two to three weeks. I have tried everything and nothing works!

Comment: @Catherine ok, you just need to deal with it and backup data using iCloud to take up less space